# My custom views are not rendering, no error or ticket is provided by web2py

Tags: python, matplotlib, web2py

So I'm trying to learn Web2Py. I've looked at several examples, downloaded several examples, and I've used the PHP framework CodeIgniter.

The issue I'm having is that the views I create don't appear to work. I am attempting to build a metrics dashboard for my business data. So lots of time vector style plots, correlation plots, pie charts, ...

I downloaded this example for getting plots in web2py via matplotlib (my preferred packed for this):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random, cStringIO
try:
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
except ImportError:
    raise HTTP(200,"requires matplotlib")

def plot(title='title',xlab='x',ylab='y',mode='plot',
         data={'xxx':[(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(3,3)],
               'yyy':[(0,0,.2,.2),(2,1,0.2,0.2),(2,2,0.2,0.2),(3,3,0.2,0.3)]}):
    fig=Figure()
    fig.set_facecolor('white')
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    if title: ax.set_title(title)
    if xlab: ax.set_xlabel(xlab)
    if ylab: ax.set_ylabel(ylab)
    legend=[]
    keys=sorted(data)
    for key in keys:
        stream = data[key]
        (x,y)=([],[])
        for point in stream:
            x.append(point[0])
            y.append(point[1])
        if mode=='plot':
            ell=ax.plot(x, y)
            legend.append((ell,key))
        if mode=='hist':
            ell=ax.hist(y,20)            
    if legend:
        ax.legend([x for (x,y) in legend], [y for (x,y) in legend], 
                  'upper right', shadow=True)
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    stream=cStringIO.StringIO()
    canvas.print_png(stream)
    return stream.getvalue()

def pcolor2d(title='title',xlab='x',ylab='y',
             z=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]):
    fig=Figure()
    fig.set_facecolor('white')
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    if title: ax.set_title(title)
    if xlab: ax.set_xlabel(xlab)
    if ylab: ax.set_ylabel(ylab)
    image=ax.imshow(z)
    image.set_interpolation('bilinear')
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    stream=cStringIO.StringIO()
    canvas.print_png(stream)
    return stream.getvalue()
```

This file is plot.py in models. I added the import section above `def plot` because it was missing. That part came from an application Massimo had in the example applications.

I then created this file (plot_test.py in controllers):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# try something like
def dashboard():
    myplot()
    myhist()
    myplot2()

    img1 = URL('myplot')
    img2 = URL('myhist')
    img3 = URL('myplot2')

    return dict(img1=img1, img2=img2, img3=img3)

def test(): 
    """
    Attempt to plot something
    """

    output = DIV(myplot(), _style="float:left; width:40%;") + DIV(myhist(), _style="float:right; width:40%;") + '<br>' + myplot2()

    response.flash = "Why aren't you working?"
    return output # dict(message="hello from plot_test.py") # , img=IMG(src='http://www.web2pyslices.com/init/static/basic/images/Slice.png',alt='myplot'))


def myplot():
    response.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'
    return plot(data={'my plot':[(0,0),(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16)]})

def myhist():
    response.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'
    return plot(data={'my plot':[(0,0),(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16)]},mode='hist')

def myplot2():
    response.headers['Content-Type']='image/png'
    return pcolor2d(z=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]])
```

There's some extra code in that file because I've been attempting several variations to try and find what little tweak I'm missing to get this working properly. There is an index def with a little sensitive data in it I've removed and the test def is just that a test to see if I could get it to work.

I then have this dashboard (plot_test/dashboard in views):

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>This is the plot_test/dashboard.html template</h1>
{{=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}

<div style="float:left; width:40%">
    <img src="{{=img1}}" alt="loading..." align="center"/>
</div>

<div style="float:right; width:40%">
    <img src="{{=img2}}" alt="loading..." align="center"/>
</div>

<br>

<div style="float:left; width:40%">
    <img src="{{=img3}}" alt="loading..." align="center"/>
</div>
```

Going to `../application_name/plot_test/dashboard` returns nothing more than a broken image icon. When I right click on a blank portion of the page in Chrome the Page Source option is grayed out and disabled. No error message, no ticket, no data.

However, the generic application pages that came with a new application work. Additionally, if I got to `../application_name/plot_test/myplot` or `myhist` or `myplot2` I get a plot that looks correct. There isn't anything else on the page and I've haven't created a view for them so I'm assuming this is the generic view for a plot.

Note that web2py is running on an Ubunu 12.04 machine that didn't have any previous Python install on it. I am viewing the app from my Windows box via Chrome. I had to make the tweak to db.py to get generic views to work at all for me.

My understanding is that when I visit `../application_name/plot_test/dashboard` is that I should receive the `plot_test/dashboard.html` view with the data provided by the `dashboard` def in the `plot_test.py` file in controllers. Clearly `plot_test.py` has no issue finding `plot.py` in models since it can produce the plots when I go to the plot pages individually.

Even if my usage of URL(...) is incorrect I would expect the dashboard view to show up with the provided title, text, and 3 divs holding broken image icons. Then when I click to view the source I could see where URL is pointing if it isn't correct.

I'm sure I've missed something extremely simple but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your dashboard function makes the following calls:

```
myplot()
myhist()
myplot2()
```

Each of those functions sets the content-type header to "image/png", so the browser expects a PNG image rather than HTML. There is no reason to call those functions in the dashboard function, so just remove those lines.

Comment: I had created the dashboard view via the web interface which appeared to add the .html automatically. I had not explicitly typed it. However, after your suggestion I copied the code from dashboard, deleted it, and created a new plot_test/dashboard.html with the .html explicitly included in the definition. I then pasted the code into the new file. Same result as before though.

Comment: That would make sense. I am, however, attempting to view the results of those plots in the dashboard view. Should those functions be called with the response.headers line removed? Or from the controller with the header removed? Or??

Comment: I put an if statement in front of the response.header line and now the dashboard shows but the images do not...

Comment: Thank, you... Got it just leave the myplot, myhist, and myplot2 alone without any if statement. Don't call them from the controller, only call them from the view via that IMG tag.

Comment: Yes, though technically you are not calling those functions from the view. Rather, you are specifying source URLs for IMG tags, which ultimately leads to those functions being called in the controller when the browser requests those URLs.